# Ограничить доступ к объекту из другого проекта

Tags: c#

Есть 3 проекта: A -> B, C (`->` - A имеет ссылку на проект B)

В проекте B находятся основные классы, методы и т.д., в т.ч. DTO классы, которые используются в основном для сериализации и десериализации. Проекту A эти классы видеть не нужно, поэтому у всех них стоит модификатор internal. Данные между проектом B и C передаются в формате json, а значит, их необходимо десериализовать после передачи. Из-за этого приходится создавать абсолютно одинаковые классы и в проекте B, и в проекте C, и назначать им модификатор internal.

Суть проблемы: Можно ли с помощью каких-нибудь атрибутов или механизмов ограничить видимость к этим классам из проекта A, но предоставить из проекта C, оставив реализацию этих классов только в проекте B?

Пример такого класса. Абсолютно такой же есть на проекте B и C:

```
internal class SessionDto
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDto> Orders { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public SessionDto() { }

    public SessionDto(Guid orderId, List<OrderDto> orders, int version)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        Orders = orders;
        Version = version;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынеси все классы используемый в передаче между В и С в отдельную библиотеку, пусть совместно ее используют

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak Но ведь, если я вынесу, допустим, это всё в проект `D` и добавлю ссылку на него и `B`, и `C`, то `A` тоже будет иметь доступ к нему. Получится следующая схема: `A -> B -> D <- C`. Или я не так понял? `A` имеет ссылку на `B`, `B` имеет ссылку на `D`, `C` имеет ссылку на `D`

Comment: Можно поставить у сборки B атрибут [InternalsVisibleTo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0) и дать из C доступ к внутренним классам B. Если уже B и C настолько связаны.

Comment: И откуда проект А узнает про D? Он(А) общается с В, что ему В покажет то он и увидит.

Comment: Угу, понял. Спасибо. Вопрос решён. Можете оформить оба комментария в виде ответа - поставлю галочку и плюсик

Comment: Как именно решен?

Comment: @aepot Вынес в отдельную библиотеку. Мне почему-то казалось, что ссылки на проекты работают чуть иначе, поэтому я не пробовал этот способ, хоть он кажется мега-очевидным и простым. Насчёт атрибута чуток позже почитаю, но выглядит тоже интересно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, стоит всё же ответить на вопрос, если кто-нибудь в дальнейшем столкнётся с данной проблемой.

Проблема звучит следующим образом - как ограничить доступ к объектам одного проекта, не дублируя их в других, применив модификатор доступа `internal`.

Ниже будут описаны действия, которые нужно выполнить:

- Создаём дополнительный проект `Shared.dll`.
- Добавляем ссылку на этот проект любому другому, которому необходимы internal-объекты.
- Создаём в проекте `Shared.dll` папку `Properties`, а в ней класс `AssemblyInfo.cs` (его создать можно через меню "Добавить").
- Добавляем следующие строки в этот файл:

  [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("T")]

где T - Название проекта. Visual Studio сама подскажет, какие названия можно туда ставить.

- Создаём какие-либо объекты в проекте `Shared.dll` и добавляем им модификатор доступа `internal`.

Таким образом, в указанных проектах (в файле `AssemblyInfo`) будут видны `internal` объекты, описанные в `Shared.dll`.

Пример взаимодействия:

```
internal class Shared.SomeClass //объект в проекте Shared.dll
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Добавляем в проект `B` ссылку на `Shared.dll`. Взаимодействие будет выглядеть следующим образом: `Shared.SomeClass....`

Добавляем в проект `A` ссылку на `B`. Взаимодействие будет выглядеть следующим образом: `Shared.SomeClass...` - VisualStudio покажет ошибку, т.к. не видит данный класс.

Тем не менее, создав в проекте `Shared.dll` какой-либо публичный объект:

```
public class Shared.SomeClass2 //объект в проекте Shared.dll
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

И выполнив те же действия - `Shared.SomeClass2...` - VisualStudio ничего против не скажет.

Надеюсь, помог кому-нибудь в будущем.

Спасибо **Mark Shevchenko** и **Pavlo Khyzhniak**.

Полезные ссылки:

[InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0)